# How to overcome Google indexing issue?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, googlebot, google-index, noindex

It's almost been more than 6 months i'm facing Google indexing issue my site can not be indexed. The issues are described below:

1- "Excluded by ‘noindex’ tag" although I have searched all my pages there is no such meta tag but still Google can not index them.

2-  Most of my URLs are under issue of "Crawled - currently not indexed" can somebody tell me what does this mean and how I can solved ?

Its really hard to understand Googlebot crawler mechanism
my crawler budget now is 150 requests daily

Screenshots are attached below.

Crawled - currently not indexed:
[image]

noindex tag issue:
[image]

robots.txt:
[image]

meta tag
[image]

Except meta tag and robots.txt what other place could be the reason of noindex ?

I have tried every possible tips and solution but still I could not overcome to this issue, some people said by time this issue will be solved but I can say its been more than 6 month no improvement.

Comment: That can also be in your [HTTP response header](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/block-indexing#http-response-header). Use Google's [URL Inspection tool](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/block-indexing).

Comment: I have checked HTTP response , there is no such tag .

Comment: That's sent from the server, it's not in the code as you indicated in your question. Please see the URL Inspection tool also linked to in my comment, and the linked question above since questions that [only could apply to your site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and troubleshooting individual sites are considered off-topic here, which is why we have a community wiki with a list of the most common reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get your html/css perfect first.

For example `https://maxtvs.net/channels?chname=MBC%20Maser%202`

- There are 118 `css` errors and 51 `html` errors
- I see that you are looking at `http`, yet that gets redirected to `https`.  If you are using `https`, then, of course, the `http` version will not get indexed.
- You are referring to `filexx.php` in your code, but these get redirected to `filexxx`.  You should correct your references because you are getting too many redirections.

Comment: May i know where did you got such HTML/CSS error ? from my side it does not give errors
i understand http urls can not be indexed, i was talking about https urls such https://www.maxtvs.net/   main page
about redirecting .php to without php i just added it recently

Comment: Your image has http **not** https urls.  You have to run some checking programs/sites to find errors.  The browser is not going to show them all as it tries to work despite them.  I am using two Chrome extensions called `HTML Validator` and `Validator Plus`.  It doesn't matter when you added the php redirection, you need to fix it before you complain about the GSE.

Comment: amazing answer i have fixed almost all errors, those two extensions are great, some of my error were due to minifying the file. just one question about image http in src attribute i didnt mentioned http nor https so it supposed to follow my domain right ?

Comment: i see from google live inspect tool all my image is loaded over https but yet it cant load all images